# How to efficiently group events by time in RXJS 5+

Tags: typescript, rxjs, rxjs5

I've 4 different types of events, I used `Observable.fromEvent(object, 'type1')` to convert to observable. They events are triggered has following combinations.

> 1. only type1.
> 2. type1, type2
> 3. type1, type3
> 4. type1, type4,
> 5. type2, type1, type3
> 6. type3, type4, type1

Since there is no straight forward pattern. I used merge and bufferTime. to sample out events as shown below.

```
const e1 = Observable.fromEvent(ob1, 'type1');
const e2 = Observable.fromEvent(ob1, 'type2');
const e3 = Observable.fromEvent(ob1, 'type3');
const e4 = Observable.fromEvent(ob1, 'type4');

const merged = merge(e1, e2, e3, e4);
const sampled = merged.bufferTime(500);
sampled.subscribe(e=>console.log(e));
```

Though the above code works, However data are emitted every `.5s`, if there are no events, empty data is emitted. I tried to use `buffer`, but in RXJS 5+, the buffer has only `closingselector` function.

How can I use observables such that timer starts on empty buffer and ends x+.5s, rather that sampling out every .5s.

Comment: Can you explain more clearly the behaviour that you want? Ideally, with a marble diagram.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you might want to `buffer` using [`debounceTime`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-debounceTime). The `debounceTime` operator does the following:

> Emits a value from the source Observable only after a particular time span has passed without another source emission.

In other words, it will only emit `x` seconds *after* the most recent emission. So, you won't end up with any empty data emissions.

You can use this with [`buffer`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-buffer) to collect "chunks" of emissions from your master stream, like so:

```
const second = 1000;
const debounced = merged.debounceTime(.5 * second);
const sampled = merged.buffer(debounced);
```

I actually wrote a blog post about collecting clicks on a button, which uses this exact approach (and goes into more detail): http://www.vincecampanale.com/blog/2017/05/24/learn-rxjs-with-a-button/.

Comment: Glad I could help :)